# How expensive is application -> DB call? (i.e. Java JDBC -> Oracle)?

Tags: java, database, oracle

There's always a "do everything in application service layer" vs "do everything in a DB procedure" argument in my workplace.

What I got is making application server and DB communicate too often is a rather expensive operation. My question is - just how expensive is it?

Say we have this example - I have a list of users in my Java application, and I need to bind a certain attribute to each of them. Let's say there are 20 users, and 20 attributes to be stored. Just how much more expensive is it to make 20 calls to an Oracle procedure using parameters (employee_id, attribute_value) rather than making 1 call, and sending all employee_ids and their matching attribute_values at once?

edit:

Ok, maybe I didn't state my case clearly - I'll "dumbify" it a bit :)

How much more expensive is it to make n calls to an Oracle procedure that does 1 insert, rather than making 1 call to an Oracle procedure that does n inserts (where n inserts are basically looping 1 insert n times)? The reason behind doing it in n calls rather than in 1 go is that, for a newbie, it's definitely easier to write a loop in Java that does n procedure calls with simple datatypes as input objects (i.e. integer, varchar2 etc) than to think of a way to pass an array from Java to Oracle.

Comment: Did you benchmark it or measure it? It probably depends a lot of your particular system (e.g. is the database server on the same machine as the application)!

Comment: Uhm, no. We are measuring our HTTP response durations, but other than that I don't think we have any statistics.

Also, we're running a Spring based Java web application on Tomcat 5.5, using Oracle JDBC driver to connect to an Oracle 10 DB. Unfortunately, I don't know much of the other technical things that would be of much help, other than the fact that app and DB are on separate machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take a case by case view of how expensive it is to get data. Dependes on the SLA that you are adhering to.
In the example that you took, if not all users are logged into your application simultaneously and the "attribute" has different value for each user, there is no point in fetching it all in one go. 
If however some attributes above represent static data, it makes sense to cache them in the application and use the cached data.

You really need to make a case by case decision. Just because it is expensive to fetch data doesnt mean you fetch it all in one go.

As for how expensive it will be, if you are using a datasource and connection pool (which almost all apss use these days), and if you use prepared statement, use BULK COLLECT statements in your procedures, or if you are using hibernate (use optimum fetch size), it should not be very costly.
The relation is definitely not linear i.e. it wont cost you 20 times a single call.